NX Daemon not running and can't start it
Currently I'm developing apps and libraries using NX for mono repository. The apps and libraries are being developed inside a docker container using Visual Studio Code and making use of a Dev Container.
When I try to serve an application from this repository like yarn nx serve appName I get this message:
NX Daemon is not running. Node process will not restart automatically after file changes.

Then the application is being served like normal, but with any code change I have to restart it manually.
Running yarn nx daemon start results in
Nx Daemon is not running.
Done in 0.25s.

Things I tried:

Reset with nx reset
Add "useDaemonProcess": true to nx.json
Upgraded to latest version (19.6.1)
Reinstall all modules
Disabled and uninstalled the NX Console plugin

nx report gives this:
Node           : 20.15.0
OS             : linux-x64
Native Target  : x86_64-linux
yarn           : 1.22.22

nx                 : 19.6.1
@nx/js             : 19.6.1
@nx/jest           : 19.6.1
@nx/linter         : 19.6.1
@nx/eslint         : 19.6.1
@nx/workspace      : 19.6.1
@nx/devkit         : 19.6.1
@nx/eslint-plugin  : 19.6.1
@nx/nest           : 19.6.1
@nx/node           : 19.6.1
@nx/plugin         : 19.6.1
@nrwl/tao          : 19.6.1
@nx/vite           : 19.6.1
@nx/vue            : 19.6.1
@nx/web            : 19.6.1
@nx/webpack        : 19.6.1
typescript         : 5.5.4
---------------------------------------
Registered Plugins:
@nx/webpack/plugin
@nx/eslint/plugin
@nx/jest/plugin
---------------------------------------
Community plugins:
@nx-tools/nx-prisma : 6.1.0
---------------------------------------
Local workspace plugins:
         @own-lib/prisma-plugin

What can I do to get the daemon started again so it will automatically start the service on code change?
Update:
No I have the NX Daemon started but it doesn't register the changes. It also says the daemon is not started:
yarn nx daemon status
yarn run v1.22.22
$ /workspaces/project/node_modules/.bin/nx daemon status
Nx Daemon is currently running:
  - Logs: /workspaces/project/.nx/workspace-data/d/daemon.log
  - Process ID: 38437
Done in 0.23s.

Tried to do a yarn nx reset and also a yarn nx daemon stop and a yarn nx daemon start . Got a new PID but still it doesn't detect the changes. So I have to manually restart it everytime I change the code.
yarn nx run example-project:serve --configuration=development 

yarn run v1.22.22
$ /workspaces/project/node_modules/.bin/nx run example-project:serve --configuration=development
The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.

 NX   Running target serve for project example-project and 1 task it depends on:

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

> nx run example-project:build  [local cache]

> webpack-cli build --node-env=production

chunk (runtime: main) main.js (main) 320 KiB [entry] [rendered]
webpack compiled successfully (2136661d531458b0)

> nx run example-project:serve:development

NX Daemon is not running. Node process will not restart automatically after file changes.
The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.

> nx run example-project:build  [local cache]

> webpack-cli build --node-env=production

chunk (runtime: main) main.js (main) 320 KiB [entry] [rendered]
webpack compiled successfully (2136661d531458b0)

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 NX   Successfully ran target build for project example-project (41ms)

Nx read the output from the cache instead of running the command for 1 out of 1 tasks.

This is the Daemon log after a reset:
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.401Z - [REQUEST]: Responding to the client. project-graph
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.403Z - Time taken for 'total for creating and serializing project graph' 2760.880134ms
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.406Z - Done responding to the client project-graph
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.406Z - Handled REQUEST_PROJECT_GRAPH. Handling time: 2761. Response time: 5.
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.420Z - [REQUEST]: Client Request for Project Graph Received
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.420Z - [REQUEST]: Responding to the client. project-graph
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.422Z - Time taken for 'total for creating and serializing project graph' 0.521443999999974ms
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.427Z - Done responding to the client project-graph
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.427Z - Handled REQUEST_PROJECT_GRAPH. Handling time: 0. Response time: 7.
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:16:44.441Z - Established a connection. Number of open connections: 2



[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:17:28.808Z - [WATCHER]: Processing file changes in outputs
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:17:31.171Z - [WATCHER]: Processing file changes in outputs
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:17:32.663Z - [WATCHER]: Processing file changes in outputs
[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-10-08T08:17:33.385Z - [WATCHER]: Processing file changes in outputs

Any suggestions?
